# Can the historical data of temporary variables be used in the defined function of reactive state engine?

Tags: time-series, dolphindb

Can the historical data of temporary variables be used in the defined function of reactive state engine?

The following is the script:

```py
@state
def multi_factor(ask_price1, ask_price2, ask_price3, ask_price4, ask_price5, ask_volume1, ask_volume2, ask_volume3, ask_volume4,ask_volume5, bid_price1, bid_price2, bid_price3, bid_price4, bid_price5, bid_volume1, bid_volume2, bid_volume3, bid_volume4, bid_volume5)
{
 factor_1 = func_1(ask_price1, ask_price2)
 factor_2 = (ask_volume1, ask_volume2)
 factor_3 = func_3(ask_price1, ask_volume1, bid_price1, bid_volume1)
 factor_3_r = factor_3/mstd(factor_3, 10)
 
 return factor_1, factor_2, factor_3_r
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in DolphinDB, you can define a state function by @state. The ihistorical data of temporary variables in the state function will be retained.